# Como guardar variables para el settings de Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo mi proyecto ya creado, pensé en poner el repo en publico así los reclutadores pueden ver el código pero tengo varias líneas que tendrían que estar en una variable. Como hago para guardarlas en una variable?

Estas son las lineas:

```
SECRET_KEY = '*********'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*****'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '******'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La problemática que expones es muy común en muchos proyectos.

Debes pasar al siguiente nivel de "calidad" en tu código/programa.

El siguiente nivel trata de no definir campos sensibles, configuraciones [...] de forma estática en ficheros, sino que debes pasarlos dinámicamente con variables de entorno / fichero `.env`/ `.ini`. De esa forma puedes compartir código de forma segura, y a la vez puedes escalar de forma exponencial, que también es importante.

Te pongo los dos paquetes mas actuales, escoja uno de ellos:

- [django-environ](https://django-environ.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#django-environ)
- [python-decouple](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple)

Te pongo un ejemplo con `python-decouple` que en mi opinión parece mas fácil y muy completo - de entrada acepta configuración vía `.env` / `.ini` o variables de entorno directamente :

En el caso de querer configurar un fichero, `.env` :

```
DEBUG=True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True
SECRET_KEY=ARANDOMSECRETKEY
DATABASE_URL=mysql://myuser:mypassword@myhost/mydatabase
PERCENTILE=90%
#COMMENTED=42
################# Y AÑADIRIAS TUS VARIABLES###################3
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '****'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '****'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*****'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '******'
```

fichero `setttings.py`

```
# coding: utf-8
from decouple import config
from unipath import Path
from dj_database_url import parse as db_url


BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent

DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

DATABASES = {
    'default': config(
        'DATABASE_URL',
        default='sqlite:///' + BASE_DIR.child('db.sqlite3'),
        cast=db_url
    )
}

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST', default='localhost')
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', default=25, cast=int)
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', default='')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER', default='')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', default=False, cast=bool)

# ...
```

[Fuente codigo ejemplo](https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple#example-how-do-i-use-it-with-django)

Comment: Una pregunta, el ARANDOMSECRETKEY, va eso o se pone la secret_key que da django?

Comment: La que queiras, aleatoria. La puedes crear así: from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
>>> unique_id = get_random_string(length=32)

Comment: Añado solo que también se puede hacer a mano si quieres evitarte una dependencia más en tu proyecto, basta crear un archivo config.cof y leerlo.